# Best way to implement pointer in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, pointers

In Objective-C it is quite common to use boolean pointers to stop an enumeration e.g.:

```
[myArray rh_iterate:^(id element, int index, BOOL *stop){
    // Do cool stuff
    *stop = YES;
}];
```

I've implemented this like:

```
// This is in a category of NSArray
- (void)rh_iterate:(void (^)(id, int, BOOL *))block
{
    if (!block) { return; }

    BOOL stop = NO;
    for (int i = 0; i < self.count; i++) {
        block(self[i], i, &stop);
        if (stop) { return; } 
    }
}
```

I'm now implementing my version of this in Swift but **am not relying on any Objective-C source code**. I know that swift likes to restrict the access of pointers so what's the best way to go about implementing this? (Ideally completely avoiding pointers.)

EDIT:

The most direct way is:

```
func rh_iterate(callback: (Element, Int, UnsafeMutablePointer<Bool>) -> ()) {

        var stop: Bool = false
        for (index, element) in self.enumerate() {
            callback(element, index, &stop)
            if stop { return }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly? The most direct equivalent would be an `inout` parameter. If I were to stick to this "route" you're going down, I would just make the closure return a `bool`. But if you tell me more of the context, I'm sure there's a much better solution we can come up with.

Comment: My trick to translate from a language to another one is to... forget the language. Read the original one *with plain English sentences*, like "ok, it takes this thing, then it loops on this and removes that, then it ...". Once you get the process as sentences, it's much easier to reimplement it in the new language than to make a real translation.

Comment: @EricD Image assembly programmers coming into Swift asking how to `bne` on register 1

Comment: Exactly. Unless you are asking just for curiosity, you don't necessarily have to solve a problem in Swift with the same logic of Objective-C. Tell us what the problem is and we'll help you.

Comment: Ok so what I'd like to achieve is an early stop to an iteration from within a closure. (I.e. the stop is in the closure and the iteration is outside.) Also I'd like to avoid having to return a bool from the closure just so i don't HAVE to return `false` just to have the iteration continue. As I understand it I can't just call `break` (just tried in Xcode and it flagged an error.)

Comment: Opinion based? Rubbish. There is a direct equivalent pattern as evidenced in my answer.

Comment: @JeremyP agree, I've got a similar answer, though one that avoids the inout and mutation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since [AMomchilov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3141234/amomchilov) deleted his answer, I'll put it back.

The direct equivalent to the `BOOL*` pattern would be an inout variable

```
extension Array
{
    func iterateWithStop(closure: (Element, inout shouldStop: Bool) -> ()) -> Bool
    {
        var shouldStop = false
        for e in self
        {
            guard !shouldStop else { return false }
            closure(e, shouldStop: &shouldStop)
        }
        return !shouldStop
    }
}
```

The function returns true if the iteration completed without the closure trying to stop it, false if the closure did try to stop it.

You would use it like this:

```
let myArray = [1, 2, 3,  -1, 4]

var sum = 0
let didProcessAllElements = myArray.iterateWithStop{ e, shouldStop in
    if e < 0 
    {
        shouldStop = true
    }
    else
    {
        sum += e
    }
}

// sum == 6
```

(tested in a playground on Swift 2.2)

Comment: I just created a little `XCTest` for this and it works nicely.

Comment: With a bit of work, you can turn it into an extension on `SequenceType` and then it will be usable on any sequence.